# Making ajax call from submit id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form in which currently posts to a hard coded php page in the action of the form, this works fine, it posts to the DB no problem, but where things get tricky for me is I don't want to post to a new page so I have opted to use ajax. So I got rid of the action field from the form and put in some jquery to make an ajax call. the issues I am having is well..it doesn't work :D. Could someone take a look at my js file and explain to me what I am doing wrong or what I should do?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">

  <form>
      <p>Comment</p>
      <textarea name= "comment" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" name= "submit" value="submit" id = "submit">
    </form>
```

```js
$('#submit').on('click',function(){
       $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST',
            url         : 'comment.php',
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json',
      })
   });
```

Comment: please refer here https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should handle the 'submit' event of the form over the 'click' event of the submit button.  You should also `return false;` at the end of function to prevent the form from posting to a new page.  You are handling the submit yourself.  Also I would put the `action` attribute back on the form element for the rare occasion that JavaScript is disabled on the client.  Give the form an id and target that.  Your code is correct otherwise.

**HTML**

```
    <form id="my-form" action="comment.php" method="post">
        <!-- input fields -->
    </form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(){ 
        // code...

        return false;
    });
```

Providing the `action` attribute, as well as the `method` attribute, on the `form` element will make these available to access in your submit handler as well as providing a proper fallback for any JavaScript failures.  That may not be necessary for this instance but may be helpful in the future.

Your handler could now look something like this:

**JavaScript**

```
    $('#my-form').on('submit', function(){ 

        // serialize the form
        var formData = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type        : this.method,
            url         : this.action,
            data        : formData,
            dataType    : 'json'
        })
        .done(function (data) { 
            // do some stuff with 'data'
        })
        .fail(function (error) {
            // do some stuff with 'error'
        });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer very through. What I don't understand is my code will always work with the hard coded action in the form call, but never without it, which means the ajax is never really doing the work.

Comment: I just can't for the life me of understand how no one has any idea why the ajax call is never made :O

Comment: Do you have `return false;` at the end of your function?  That should prevent the page from posting and allow the ajax call.

Comment: I do have it, I have also taken out the action and post from the form tg together for testing. So I just got back to working on this, this morning and I put a console.log statement right after the form id is clicked to see if the jquery is even working, and it wont log to the console. I put it in the function right above which is working, so it's making it to the jquery, but when the form is submitted, no console  log.

Comment: I read a similar post that said changing the name of  `submit` to something else other than submit, would help this, however, it had no affect. :O this is a real headache

Comment: Strange.  Are you getting any errors?  The only thing I can see based off the code you provided is that you are not serializing the form. `var formData = $(this).serialize();`.  I was assuming that you have done that.

Comment: No I have not, still very new to web dev, I come from an OOP background. would that prevent something like this from working??

Comment: the $ in front of my ajax is not the same color as all the other $, would that be an indicator I'm including $.ajax wrong in my js file?

Comment: Yes that would prevent it from working.  `formData` would be `undefined` and would prevent the call causing in an error instead.  I'm sure you're including your js file correctly otherwise the submit handler wouldn't work at all.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include serialization of the form and a fail handler.

Comment: Ah ha! that posted it!!! Okay would you mind breaking that down for me? Why does that do the trick, and one other question, so it posts the data, but when you hit submit it's almost like you can't tell, like the data stays in the comment box and nothing changes.

Comment: It failed because you never defined the variable so it chocked on it.  serialize takes the inputs from the form and creates an object which `$.ajax` needs to send to the server.   To better understand the code I would look at jQuery's [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/).  It's very detailed.  Also look at the tutorial link Jose CC provided.  Here's the link for [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/).  To better understand javascript in general take a look at Mozilla's [documentation and turorials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript)

Comment: This guy ^^^^ helped me a ton, Thanks Chuckles, have a good rest of the day. Thanks for all the documentation as well. take it easy buddy.

Comment: No problem.  Also take a look at [BlockUI plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/).  You can use it to indicate when AJAX is running during the form submit.  Might be helpful.  Otherwise you can present some text to the user on submit and clear it in the `done` or `always` handler's of the `$.ajax` function.

Comment: Will do. Working on the .done function now. Would you happen to have any recommendations on ajax books? I have good web dev (jquery, javascript, ect) but no ajax book. Any suggestions on good ones?

Comment: I haven't read any on jQuery or AJAX specifically but [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](https://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Definitive-Guide-David-Flanagan/product-reviews/0596101996) is a must if you're going to be using JavaScript. It can be a bit intimidating so I would wait till you get a handle on JS first.

Comment: Thanks Chuckles, take care!